# How can I remove a specific object from my array based on object values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following array of objects in javascript.

```
[{
     's': 'ETHBTC',
     'q': 123456
},
{
     's': 'XMLBTC',
     'q': 545454
},
{
     's': 'ETHBTC',
     'q': 123451
}]
```

I want to remove the duplicate objects based on condition that if all the objects have same value of the key `s`,I want to keep the only one that has the highest value of key `q`. In the above example, I would want to only keep

```
[{
     's': 'ETHBTC',
     'q': 123456
},
{
     's': 'XMLBTC',
     'q': 545454
}]
```

because it has highest value of key `q` for key `s : ETHBTC` and `s : XMLBTC` was missing so I pushed it into the array. What can be the best approach for it?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: is the above single object the complete result?

Comment: Nopes Let me edit it

Answer (score 6):

I'd `reduce` into an object indexed by `s`, checking whether the current object at that index (if any) has a higher or lower `q`, and then getting the `Object.values` of the result to turn it back into an array:

```js
const input = [{
     's': 'ETHBTC',
     'q': 123456
},
{
     's': 'XMLBTC',
     'q': 545454
},
{
     's': 'ETHBTC',
     'q': 123451
}];
console.log(
  Object.values(
    input.reduce((a, item) => {
      const { s, q } = item;
      if (!a[s] || a[s].q < q) a[s] = item;
      return a;
    }, {})
  )
);
```

ES5 compatible solution:

```js
var input = [{
     's': 'ETHBTC',
     'q': 123456
},
{
     's': 'XMLBTC',
     'q': 545454
},
{
     's': 'ETHBTC',
     'q': 123451
}];

var outputObj = input.reduce(function (a, item) {
  var s = item.s,
      q = item.q;

  if (!a[s] || a[s].q < q) a[s] = item;
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(
  Object.keys(outputObj).map(key => outputObj[key])
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is not supported by my javascript

Comment: What do you mean, not supported? Use Babel in your build process if you need to support obsolete browsers, that way you can write with the latest syntax (same with polyfills)